# Prove that doesnt exist $f$ that $f(0)=1$ and$ |z|^2+1\leq |f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f$ and holomorphic in B(0,1) and $f(0)=1$ ,$ |z|^2+1\leq |f(z)|$ prove that such $f$ doesn't exist.

I've thought maybe to use the maximum principal but didnt manage

Comment: Just like that? No conditions on $\;f\;$ *at all*? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I forgot that $f$ is holomorphic and i edited rightnow,I thought maybe to define $g(z)=1\f(z)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $f$ is holomorphic on $B(0,1)$, therefore the function $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^2+1}$$ is also holomorphic on $B(0,1)$ and from condition $|z|^2+1\leq |f(z)|$, we have $$|z^2+1|\leq|z|^2+1\leq |f(z)|$$ which implies
$$|g(z)|\geq 1$$
can you proceed now?

Comment: How did you derive $|g(z)| \le 1$?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, my bad. I'm going to edit the post. Thanks

Comment: now i can look on 1/g and get from MMP that g is constant no?

Comment: @ronkurman Yes you are.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Comment: @ronkurman   youre welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ never vanishes. Now $|f(z)| \geq 1$ for all $z$ and $f(0)=1$. This implies that $\frac  1f$ is a holomorphic function which attains its maximum at an interior point. By MMP this implies that $f(z)$ is a constant and since $f(0)=1$ we get $f(z)=1$ for all $z$. But then the given inequality fails.